# Need to split a single form into multiple components in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-components, angular4-forms

I have 1 larger form which contains 10 sections. I am planning to split that 1 form into multiple components (Nested).

If i create nested components i need associate the FormGroup in the main component (That is tightly coupled). Instead of that is there any other possible solution we have (I am looking for a loosely coupled) in Angular 2 /4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having the parent container hold the form and it's form groups and then passing the form to the children make for less code within the children, for example

```
<child-comp [form]="parentForm"> or
<child-comp [form]="parentForm.controls.myFormGroup">
```

However, if you don't want to pass the form at all, then you can just create the form group in the child.  **But**, you will have to pass the data back up to the parent so the parent can use it or pass it to another child.

There are several ways a parent can reference a child to get its form group

- `@ViewChild(InfoComponent) private info: InfoComponent;`
- `@Output() infoUpdated = new EventEmitter();`
- A shared service